# Reg: izPack dynamic variables

Tags: izpack

How to assign dynamic variable value from file in izPack.

Can you please post some code snippet?

I tried it with the following syntax:

```
    <variable name="EXIST_IP_ADDRESS" file="${INSTALL_PATH}/test.properties" 
type="options" key="IpAddress"/>
```

But am getting error says that value attribute is mandatory. If I assign value with some string then this cannot be loaded from file. Please check what mistakes am doing.

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic variables have their own section, I guess you are trying to use it in "variables" section.

```
<dynamicvariables>
  <variable name="previous.JAVA_HOME" escape="false" file="${INSTALL_PATH}/run.cmd" type="options" key="SET JRE" ignorefailure="true">
</dynamicvariables>
```